# List of Vectors need some basics

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

**hi i have these Vectors :**

```
    Vector2 ground1p1 = new Vector2(0,430);
    Vector2 ground1p2 = new Vector2(200,430);
    Vector2 ground1p3 = new Vector2(0, 290);
    Vector2 ground1p4 = new Vector2(280, 340);
```

**i want to put them in a list so instead of doing this :**

```
if (DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(playerPosition,ground1p1,player,ground1) == true)
            {
                hasJumped = false;
                velocity.Y = 0f;
            }
            if (DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(playerPosition, ground1p2, player, ground1) == true)
            {
                hasJumped = false;
                velocity.Y = 0f;
            }
```

**here is the problem when i write "vectors" in the end of the writtings nothing happens like i havent declared is as a list :**

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
     {

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;




        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize();
        }


        bool hasJumped = true;


        Vector2 velocity;
        Texture2D player;
        Texture2D ground1;
        List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>();


        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(30, 300);
        Vector2 ground1p1 = new Vector2(0,430);
        Vector2 ground1p2 = new Vector2(200,430);
        Vector2 ground1p3 = new Vector2(0, 290);
        Vector2 ground1p4 = new Vector2(280, 340);
```

Comment: I don't think adding another loop will help with the performance of XNA. Honestly appropriate data structures could handle this better.

Comment: i know it wont help lol :D i want it to be easy for me for further writtings i dont rly want to copy paste 100 times

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list (as you suggested)

```
List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>();

vectors.Add(ground1p1);
vectors.Add(ground1p2);
vectors.Add(ground1p3);
vectors.Add(ground1p4);

foreach (Vector2 vec2 in vectors) 
{
    if (DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(playerPosition, vec2, player, ground1))
    {
        hasJumped = false;
        velocity.Y = 0f;         

        // maybe add a break to prevent superfluous calls
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>(); doesnt work
when i add vectors to the list errors appear

Comment: You probably need `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your file.  See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: well List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>(); when i write vectors.add "vectors" is a field and its used like a type

Comment: after  public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
     {